# PrintSteam Full output only creates last data set

Tags: java, file-writing

My program compiles and will write to a .txt file however it only writes the last data set size 1000. I am trying to get it to write all ten sizes to one .txt file. If I take away the PrintSteam method the full output will include all ten data sets. How would I make all ten write to the .txt file? Below is the main code and the section from the BenchmarkSorts class that writes to the file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SortMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        int[] sizes = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000};
        new BenchmarkSorts(sizes);
    }
}
```

```
    try {
        // Creating a File object that represents the disk file. 
        PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new File("BenchmarkSort.txt")); 

        // Store current System.out before assigning a new value 
        PrintStream console = System.out; 

        // Assign o to output stream 
        System.setOut(o); 

        // Produces output
        System.out.println("Data Set Size (n): " + arraySize +
        "\n\tIterative Selection Sort Results: \t\t\t\t\tRecursive Selection Sort Results:" +
        "\n\tAverage Critical Operation Count: " + Math.round(iterativeAverageCount) +
        "\t\t\tAverage Critical Operation Count: " + Math.round(recursiveAverageCount) +
        "\n\tStandard Deviation of Count: " + Math.round(iterativeSDCount) +
        "\t\t\t\t\tStandard Deviation of Count: " + Math.round(recursiveSDCount) +
        "\n\tAverage Execution Time: " + Math.round(iterativeAverageTime) +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\tAverage Execution Time: " + Math.round(recursiveAverageTime) +
        "\n\tStandard Deviation of Time: " + Math.round(iterativeSDTime) +
        "\t\t\t\t\t\tStandard Deviation of Time: " + Math.round(recursiveSDTime));

         // Use stored value for output stream 
        System.setOut(console); 
        System.out.println("Output File is now BenchmarkSort.txt");
    } 
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {

    }
```

Comment: Didn't I see this same code before in another question?! It would be easier if you stuck to the one question instead of reposting same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that the try-catch is in place (I would still recommend using try-with-resource, so everyhting get's closed properly!), you need to create the output stream into the file in an appending way:

```
 //Create an appending file output stream
 FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(new File("BenchmarkSort.txt"), true);
 //Now create the print-stream
 PrintStream o = new PrintStream(fo);
```

Now every time the file is opened, it's opened in append mode - so new content is written to the end of the file.

make sure to close the streams before returning! Using try-with-resource would already do this for you:

```
 //Create an appending file output stream
 try(FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(new File("BenchmarkSort.txt"), true);
  //Now create the print-stream
  PrintStream o = new PrintStream(fo)) {



} // <- this will automatically close the streams!
```

Comment: Thank you this makes much more sense to me now!